# Unable to upload files in SilverStripe 4

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've created a simple extension to `SiteConfig` to add a logo uploadfield to the settings section. However, the server returns an error upon uploading a file.

**SiteConfig.php**

```
namespace mymodule\siteconfig;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\AssetAdmin\Forms\UploadField;

class SiteConfig extends DataExtension {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Logo' => 'SilverStripe\\Assets\\File'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $logo = UploadField::create('Logo', 'Logo upload'));

    }

}
```

[image: Error]

Server's error log does not show anything relevant to this error. Whats going on here?

**UPDATE**

I just tried to upload a file to the Files section in the CMS, got the exact same error.

Comment: I think you may need to change the $has_one array setup to something like this: 'Logo' => 'Image'

Comment: 'Logo' => 'Image' won't work as global classes are gone in ss4. Prefer 'Logo' => File::class or 'Image' => Image::class to hardcoding FQCNs as strings. As for the error, it's unlikely related to your code. 503 is much more likely a problem with your environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static $has_one = [
    'LogoImage' => Image::class,
];

public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {

   $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', UploadField::create('LogoImage', 'Logo'));

}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: You have to just replace above code into your solution, it will work. You already display a screenshot of your problem so it is not a big deal to use this code in your solution.